# Reuse code while mocking external funcs when testing golang aws lambdas

Tags: go

I have AWS lambdas in my golang app.
Wanted to write unit tests for it:

```
func TestHandleLambdaEvent(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    //mockNewAuthContextWithMap()
    oldNewAuthContextWithMap := NewAuthContextWithMap
    defer func() { NewAuthContextWithMap = oldNewAuthContextWithMap }()
    NewAuthContextWithMap = func(stringifiedMap map[string]interface{}) (*authutils.AuthContext, error) {
        return &authutils.AuthContext{UserID: "12345", Org: "XYZOrg", Role: "Member", Timestamp: 999999999}, nil
    }

    //mockLambdaInvoke()
    old := LambdaInvoke
    defer func() { LambdaInvoke = old }()
    LambdaInvoke = func(context context.Context, arn string, request, response interface{}) error { return nil }

    resp, err := handleLambdaEvent(ctx, events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("handleLambdaEvent returned error: %v", err)
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        t.Fatalf("Invalid status code, provded: %d required %d", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusOK)
    }
}
```

this test code works fine, but.. I would like to put code under *mockNewAuthContextWithMap* to func ie:

```
func mockNewAuthContextWithMap() {
    old := NewAuthContextWithMap
    defer func() { NewAuthContextWithMap = old }()
    NewAuthContextWithMap = func(stringifiedMap map[string]interface{}) (*authutils.AuthContext, error) {
        return &authutils.AuthContext{UserID: "12345", Org: "XYZOrg", Role: "Member", Timestamp: 999999999}, nil
    }
}
```

and simply call it from the test. Then it does not work.
I assume its due to defer func, which simply run before test will call handler.

how can I fix it ?
looks like I can reuse this part of code:

```
NewAuthContextWithMap = func(stringifiedMap map[string]interface{}) (*authutils.AuthContext, error) {
        return &authutils.AuthContext{UserID: "12345", Org: "XYZOrg", Role: "Member", Timestamp: 999999999}, nil
    }
```

but saving old function value with defer func that will rollback it must be repeated everytime.

EDIT:

probably only what I can do is:

```
func TestHandleLambdaEvent(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    mockNewAuthContextWithMap()
    mockLambdaInvoke()

    resp, err := handleLambdaEvent(ctx, events.APIGatewayProxyRequest{})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("handleLambdaEvent returned error: %v", err)
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        t.Fatalf("Invalid status code, provded: %d required %d", resp.StatusCode, http.StatusOK)
    }

    defer RollbackExternalMethods()
}

// LambdaInvoke
func mockNewAuthContextWithMap() {
    NewAuthContextWithMap = func(stringifiedMap map[string]interface{}) (*authutils.AuthContext, error) {
        return &authutils.AuthContext{UserID: "12345", Org: "XYZOrg", Role: "Member", Timestamp: 999999999}, nil
    }
}

// LambdaInvoke
func mockLambdaInvoke() {
    LambdaInvoke = func(context context.Context, arn string, request, response interface{}) error { return nil }
}

func RollbackExternalMethods() {
    NewAuthContextWithMap = authutils.NewAuthContextWithMap
    LambdaInvoke = lambdaClient.Invoke
}
```

EDIT: handleLambdaEvent

```
func handleLambdaEvent(context context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
authContext, err := NewAuthContextWithMap(request.RequestContext.Authorizer)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error parsing auth context:", err)
    return awsutils.StatusResponse(http.StatusInternalServerError), nil
}

queryRequest := handlerInput.GetProfile{
    Type:   handlerInput.TypeGetProfile,
    UserId: authContext.UserID,
}

queryResp := dbModel.User{}
err = LambdaInvoke(context, userServiceArn, queryRequest, &queryResp)
if err != nil {
    if ierrError, ok := err.(ierr.Error); ok {
        if ierrError.IsSame(user.RecordNotFoundError) {
            fmt.Printf("Could not find user profile of userId: %s \n", authContext.UserID)
            emptyResp := dbModel.User{}
            return awsutils.SwaggerResponse(http.StatusOK, emptyResp.SwaggerModel()), nil
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("Error invoking lambda:", err)
    return awsutils.StatusResponse(http.StatusInternalServerError), nil
}

swagUser := queryResp.SwaggerModel()
return awsutils.SwaggerResponse(http.StatusOK, swagUser), nil
```

}

Comment: Can you post also the code of the AWS Lambda? Thanks!

Comment: To me, it's still hard to repro. Lots of missing functions/variables/constants. Nothing that compiles. Also, you can try to isolate your issue and post a more reproducible example. Let me know!

Comment: well you wont repro it so easily, coz its calling aws lambdas ;) but I think I can achieve my goal using testify easily

Comment: you didn't get my point. Anyway, I used several times the `testify/suite` package and it's very valuable. So if that's everything you need, go ahead & good luck

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/stretchr/testify#suite-package

testify has nice features like before, after test etc. by using this its easy to avoid copy pasting the sam parts of code